# suppress grep directory warnings globally

Tags: linux, grep

For certain obvious usages, the **grep** command can output multiple complaints about search names being directories.  Note the multiple "Is a directory" warnings, this typically happens with commands like:  grep *text* *

eg:

```
/etc/webmin # grep "log=1" * 
grep: cluster-webmin: Is a directory
config:log=1
grep: cpan: Is a directory
grep: man: Is a directory
miniserv.conf:log=1
miniserv.conf:syslog=1
grep: mon: Is a directory
```

I know I can use the "-s" option to suppress these warnings about directories (and stderr can be redirected to nul, but that's even worse), but I don't like that because it's extra boilerplate which we have to remember *every* time, and it also suppresses *all* warnings, not just ones about directories.

Is there some way, where this spurious warning can be suppressed forever and globally ?  I'm most interested in Debian and Cygwin.

Comment: The reason: grep don't know what to do with directories. Please tell him (with -d) to either recurse (read directories and subdirectories recursively) or skip

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on the way you want to handle directories contents,

- `grep -d recurse` will do it (handling recursively directories), or
- `grep -d skip` (ignoring directories and their content).

You could have this be automatic, by adding it to ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc (one user) or /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc (all users)

```
alias grep="/bin/grep -d skip"
```

Comment: This works nicely.  I also found something called GREP_OPTIONS where the "-d skip" could be added instead.  However, some bright spark somewhere decided that GREP_OPTIONS has been deprecated, and prints an annoying message when used, alas.  So adding this as an alias (to profile or bashrc or whereever) is the best option.  alias grep='/bin/grep -d skip'

Comment: @William - they'll remove `GREP_OPTIONS` due to problems it causes when writing portable scripts - hence the warning...

Answer (score 0):

You could set an alias in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
alias grep='grep -s'
```

For global you could do it in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: I realize I can do this, and it would help with many cases of suppressing this warning.  But, I am hoping for something which does not alter how grep is invoked/executed, and which won't suppress other grep warnings, and would work even for when grep isn't run (directly) by the shell.

Comment: As long as it's in your bashrc it will work from within scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, GNU grep honours an environment variable called `GREP_OPTIONS`. From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
GREP_OPTIONS
      This variable specifies default options to be placed in front of
      any explicit options.  As  this  causes  problems  when  writing
      portable  scripts,  this  feature  will  be  removed in a future
      release of grep, and grep warns if it is used.   Please  use  an
      alias or script instead.
```

You can do `export GREP_OPTIONS=-s`, but, as the manpage says, this will also get passed on to scripts and might unintentionally mess up things.

For example, I have had `GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always` mess up `configure` scripts used for building software. Debugging that was a pain, it wasn't at all clear where the problem was.

Comment: See the comments to tonioc's answer, for why your solution is undesirable.

Comment: @user1404316 please read the answer itself to see why this is undesirable.